# How do you calculate the expected value of mixed lognormal distribution?

Tags: expected-value, mixture-distribution, lognormal-distribution

Suppose $X=\log(Y)$ can be modeled by a mixture of two normal distributions with proportion $p$ of $X_1$ and proportion $1-p$ of $X_2$, where $X_1\sim\mathcal N(U_1, \sigma^2_1)$ and $X_2\sim\mathcal N(U_2, \sigma^2_2)$.

How do you calculate $E(Y)$; i.e., $E(\exp(X))$ where $X$ is a mixture of two normals?

Comment: Are you asking about a *linear combination* of normals or a *mixture*? The notation you've used is a little ambiguous in this regard and a correct answer will depend on which you are interested in.

Comment: @Cardinal Given that the OP has twice used the word "mixture" and did not equate "$p * X_1 + (1-p) * X_2$" with a $\mathcal{N}(p U_1 + (1-p)U_2, p^2 \sigma_1^2 + (1-p)^2 \sigma_2^2)$ distribution, it would be erroneous to interpret this as a linear combination, don't you think?

Comment: @whuber: I think that's very highly likely; on the other hand, both answers here have done their calculations assuming (intentionally or inadvertently) the latter rather than the former; and, there was a very recent question where this confusion popped up. So, my response was, shall we say, conservative rather than speculative. :-)

Comment: @Cardinal Thanks. And, to be perfectly clear--because I think you're holding back a little out of politeness--the answer to the mixture interpretation differs substantially from the answer to the linear combination interpretation.

Comment: I am sorry not getting back earlier. I mean mixture of normals, not linear combination of two normals.

Comment: I was thinking mixture with my answer but I wrote it like a linear combination.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll try to give an answer for the mixture case. Let's formalize the set-up. We consider a random variable $X$ and an indicator random variable $I$, with $P[I=1] = 1-P[I=2] = p$, independent of $X$. Furthermore, for the mixture we have that the law of $X$ given that $I=1$ is the law of $X_1$, which is Gaussian with mean $U_1$ and variance $\sigma^2_1$; and, if $I=2$, the law is that of $X_2$ with law $N(U_2,\sigma^2_2)$.

Then, for $Y=\exp(X)$ we can calculate the expectation as
$$
\begin{align}
E[Y] &= E[\exp(X)] = p E[\exp(X)|I=1] + (1-p) E[\exp(X)|I=2] \\
     &= p E[\exp(X_1)] + (1-p) E[\exp(X_2)] \\
     &= p \exp(U_1+ \sigma^2_1/2) + (1-p) \exp(U_2+ \sigma^2_2/2) 
\end{align}
$$
by using the expectation of a log-normal.

Comment: (+1) There are a couple (inconsequential) typos in the first paragraph.

Comment: **Follow up exercise** (*for the interested reader*): Imitate this approach to (easily) generalize to *arbitrary* finite mixture distributions *and* arbitrary (Borel measurable) function $g(x)$ in place of $\exp(x)$.

Comment: @cardinal I have corrected some ... don't see any anymore ... but it's 11pm here in Europe ...

Comment: I used this initially, but started to doubt whether it is correct. If X ~ mixed normal of X1 and X2 with mixing probability p, does that mean exp(X) ~ mixed lognormal with same mixing probability p? I started to doubt this because this estimator seems to be biased (different from sample mean) for my data. Any suggestions on how to reduce the bias?

Comment: @qqq, What estimator are you using? Up until now, all discussion has been about random variables, not data, so the idea of bias is not even applicable.

Comment: I used E[Y]=pexp(U1+σ2^1/2)+(1−p)exp(U2+σ2^2/2) as the estimator for the overall mean like what Richard suggested initially. Then I think this way we are treating p as fixed but indeed p is a random variable, therefore sth is missing there...  Please ignore my bias claim, I will try some simulation study to verify that.

Comment: @whuber: In the question it is asked how to **calculate** the mean and not how to estimate the model. I anwered how to calculate the mean which is useful if the parameters are known, which could be the case. On the other hand I will google something about the **estimation** of mixed Gaussian distribution. I am quite sure that I will find something. First thing that comes to my mind is maximum-likelihood or the EM algorithm. Later today I can probably provide more.

Comment: Google 'estimation of mixed gaussian distribution' and you find many hits .. add 'R project' and you find packages, I would try [nor1mix](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nor1mix/nor1mix.pdf) or [mixtools](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mixtools/mixtools.pdf).

Comment: qqq, Your estimator is indeed biased (as is well known). Also, $p$ is fixed: if it is a random variable, you have a more complex mixture than you first described. It sounds to me that you are not sufficiently distinguishing a model from data, which is a concern because it's leading you to keep changing your question. Please consider posting a new question in which you describe what you're really doing in terms of data collection and analysis. @Richard, I believe you intended to address your last two comments to qqq, not me.

Comment: @qqq You see that a lot of speculation is going on here how your question is meant. Can you please clarify. Is $p$ some percentage of a population on which you do statistics or is it a probability in a pure probabilistic sense. Is your question about probability theory or about statistics?

Comment: @Richard: Sorry guys, my complete story: I need to estimate mean revenue (the population is very heavy tailed). Sample mean is a natural unbiased estimator but has a  wide confidence interval.  I hope to find an estimator with smaller MSE.  I fitted normal mixture to log transformed data. The fit seems good visually. But the point estimator I got (as what Richard suggested before) seems to be different from sample mean. I wonder whether I calculated it correctly and therefore raised the original question. If right, how to reduce the bias?  Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: @qqq Thanks. This is a completely different question at this point (and it's interesting and deserves a good answer). May I suggest you accept Richard's answer and post a new question asking how to reduce the bias in your estimator? I should point out it has an obvious answer: use the arithmetic mean of the data. But there could be reasons for trying to adjust your estimator, anyway, depending on how you wish to balance the tradeoff between estimation bias and estimation variance.

Comment: @Whuber Sure, thanks whuber. I will think about it more and post a separate question once I get it clear. Do I need to close the thread or anything? Many thanks to Richard and you and others who gave feedbacks!

Comment: On the contrary, qqq: instead of closing the thread, please mark the best answer as accepted (by clicking on the gray checkmark). (I think only one currently remains undeleted, but if it works for you, then it's helpful to accept it.) That helps guide future readers to the most useful information.

Comment: @Whuber, thanks Whuber, just checked Richard's answer...

Comment: @qqq Thank you and Whuber. I am looking forward for the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

For instance, if you are dealing with a two component mixture, the first moment is calculated as follows:
$\mu_{\rm mixture}=\pi_{1} \cdot \mu_{1} +  \pi_{2} \cdot \mu_{2}$,
where $\pi_{i}\ (i=1,2)$ stands for the components' weights and $\mu_{i}\ (i=1,2)$ for the means.

Comment: This is true, as far as it goes, but it ignores the non-linear transform (exp) in the problem statement.